# php Curl get JWT in the headers

Tags: php, curl, jwt

I have a rest request, I used curl for php but I need to get the response JWT that comes in the headers to make a new request signed by JWT without needing to re-login. every time I make a request the API returns a new JWT to do another but I do not know how to get it from curl, Someone knows how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i  need enable CURLOPT_HEADER => true  in my array

Answer (score 0):

You must know the name of header element, 
this function returns assoc. array, you must only write the name of your JWT response header.

```
...
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$headers = get_headers_from_curl_response($response);

function get_headers_from_curl_response($response)
{
    $headers = array();

    $header_text = substr($response, 0, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n"));

    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header_text) as $i => $line)
        if ($i === 0)
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        else
        {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);

            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }

    return $headers;
}
```

This function makes array from CURL response.

Final variable will be this

```
$myJWT = $headers['CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_OF_JWT'];
```

Comment: thanks your function I was very useful just change in return $headers for a return (array)$headers

Comment: Dont forget arrow UP